# iOS NSURLSessionUploadTask is stuck

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I'm trying to send HTTP post message in the implementation `NSFileProviderExtension`'s method `itemChangedAtURL:(NSURL *)` using `uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest`, after I resume the task the delegate method `needNewBodyStream` is called and after it nothing happens until next time that `itemChangedAtURL:(NSURL *)` and it causes first to call to the delegate method

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)task:(NSURLSessionTask*)didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)
```

I'll appreciate any help

Thanks,

Ronen

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315141/background-upload-with-stream-request-using-nsurlsession-in-ios8 it's seems that it's not possible to use   

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession * nonnull)session task:NSURLSessionTask * nonnull)task needNewBodyStream:(void (^ nonnull)(NSInputStream * nullable bodyStream))completionHandler